# What free admin tools are available for SQL Server Express 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-express

I am developing in visual studio 2008 (new) and it would be convenient to to have an Enterprise Manager / SQL Server Development Studio like tool to manage the databases.  I am wonder what other developers who don't have acccess to SSDS are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en)

Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Management Studio Express available at:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

Does most things the full version does. But you can get a cheaper version of SQL Server for Development with the full kit I believe. I got one for 2000, cost me £30.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796)